# Batch Copy/Delete some blobs in container

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-cli, azcopy

I have a lot thousands containers and each container has up to 10k blobs inside. I have a list of tuple `(container, blob)` to

1. copy to another storage
2. delete later in the original storage

The blobs in containers are not related to each other - random date creation, random names (guids), nothing in common.

Q: is there any efficient way how to do these operations?

I already looked at `az-cli` and `azcopy` and haven't found any good way.
I tried e.g. to call `azcopy` repeatedly for each tuple, but this would take ages. One call to copy the blob took 2sec in average. So it's nice it starts operation in background, but if this "starting operation" takes about 2 seconds, it's pretty useless for my case.

Comment: So you only want to copy certain blobs from a container and not the container in its entirety?

Comment: yes, exactly @404

Comment: You could look at the `--include-path` option in azcopy so only have to run it once per container, although I'm not sure how it'll hold up with thousands of files.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming based on the comments that within each container, it's an arbitrary number (and naming) of blobs to copy and delete.  And that the delete is only for the blobs copied (not the full container).  If so, and want to use something besides REST one suggestion would be Powershell script to read from a file the list of blobs to copy (service side copy) and then separately do a delete (more efficient to do a copy and if successful, then delete)  e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/get-azstorageblobcopystate?view=azps-4.7.0#example-4--start-copy-and-pipeline-to-get-the-copy-status

Cheers, Klaas [Microsoft]